# eulerr diagram: error in data assignment and program termination

Tags: r, eulerr

I would like to create an euler diagram with R.

My Code looks like this:

```
library(eulerr)

IEEE <- c("Paper0", "Paper1", "Paper2", "Paper3", "Paper4", "Paper5", "Paper6", "Paper7", "Paper8", "Paper9", "Paper10", "Paper11", "Paper12", "Paper13", "Paper14", "Paper15", "Paper16", "Paper17", "Paper18", "Paper19", "Paper20", "Paper21", "Paper22", "Paper23", "Paper24", "Paper25", "Paper26", "Paper27", "Paper28", "Paper29", "Paper30", "Paper31", "Paper32", "Paper33", "Paper34", "Paper35", "Paper36", "Paper37", "Paper38", "Paper39", "Paper40", "Paper41", "Paper42", "Paper43", "Paper44", "Paper45", "Paper46", "Paper47", "Paper48", "Paper49", "Paper50", "Paper51", "Paper52", "Paper53", "Paper54", "Paper55", "Paper56", "Paper57", "Paper58", "Paper59", "Paper60", "Paper61", "Paper62", "Paper63", "Paper64", "Paper65", "Paper66", "Paper67", "Paper68", "Paper69", "Paper70", "Paper71", "Paper72", "Paper73", "Paper74", "Paper75", "Paper76", "Paper77", "Paper78", "Paper79", "Paper80", "Paper81", "Paper82", "Paper83", "Paper84", "Paper85", "Paper86", "Paper87", "Paper88", "Paper89", "Paper90", "Paper91", "Paper92", "Paper93", "Paper94", "Paper95", "Paper96", "Paper97", "Paper98", "Paper99", "Paper100", "Paper101", "Paper102", "Paper103", "Paper104", "Paper105", "Paper106", "Paper107", "Paper108", "Paper109", "Paper110", "Paper111", "Paper112", "Paper113", "Paper114", "Paper115", "Paper116", "Paper117", "Paper118", "Paper119", "Paper120", "Paper121", "Paper122", "Paper123", "Paper124", "Paper125", "Paper126", "Paper127", "Paper128", "Paper129", "Paper130", "Paper131", "Paper132", "Paper133", "Paper134", "Paper135", "Paper136", "Paper137", "Paper138", "Paper139", "Paper140", "Paper141", "Paper142", "Paper143", "Paper144", "Paper145", "Paper146", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "")

SpringerNature <- c("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "Paper27", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "Paper101", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "Paper135", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "Paper609", "", "", "", "", "", "Paper615", "Paper616", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "Paper633", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "Paper756", "", "Paper758", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "Paper819", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "Paper838", "Paper839", "Paper840", "Paper841", "Paper842", "Paper843", "Paper844", "Paper845", "Paper846", "Paper847", "Paper848", "Paper849", "Paper850", "Paper851", "Paper852", "Paper853", "Paper854", "Paper855", "Paper856", "Paper857", "Paper858", "Paper859", "Paper860", "Paper861", "Paper862", "Paper863", "Paper864", "Paper865", "Paper866", "Paper867", "Paper868", "Paper869", "Paper870", "Paper871", "Paper872", "Paper873", "Paper874", "Paper875", "Paper876", "Paper877", "Paper878", "Paper879", "Paper880", "Paper881", "Paper882", "Paper883", "Paper884", "Paper885", "Paper886", "Paper887", "Paper888", "Paper889", "Paper890", "Paper891", "Paper892", "Paper893", "Paper894", "Paper895", "Paper896", "Paper897", "Paper898", "Paper899", "Paper900", "Paper901", "Paper902", "Paper903", "Paper904", "Paper905", "Paper906", "Paper907", "Paper908", "Paper909", "Paper910", "Paper911", "Paper912", "Paper913", "Paper914", "Paper915", "Paper916", "Paper917", "Paper918", "Paper919", "Paper920", "Paper921", "Paper922", "Paper923", "Paper924", "Paper925", "Paper926", "Paper927", "Paper928", "Paper929", "Paper930", "Paper931", "Paper932", "Paper933", "Paper934", "Paper935", "Paper936", "Paper937", "Paper938", "Paper939", "Paper940", "Paper941", "Paper942", "Paper943", "Paper944", "Paper945", "Paper946", "Paper947", "Paper948", "Paper949", "Paper950", "Paper951", "Paper952", "Paper953", "Paper954", "Paper955", "Paper956", "Paper957", "Paper958", "Paper959", "Paper960", "Paper961", "Paper962", "Paper963", "Paper964", "Paper965", "Paper966", "Paper967", "Paper968", "Paper969", "Paper970", "Paper971", "Paper972", "Paper973", "Paper974", "Paper975", "Paper976", "Paper977", "Paper978", "Paper979", "Paper980", "Paper981", "Paper982", "Paper983", "Paper984", "Paper985", "Paper986", "Paper987", "Paper988", "Paper989", "Paper990", "Paper991", "Paper992", "Paper993", "Paper994", "Paper995", "Paper996", "Paper997", "Paper998", "Paper999", "Paper1000", "Paper1001", "Paper1002", "Paper1003", "Paper1004", "Paper1005", "Paper1006", "Paper1007", "Paper1008", "Paper1009", "Paper1010", "Paper1011", "Paper1012", "Paper1013", "Paper1014", "Paper1015", "Paper1016", "Paper1017", "Paper1018", "Paper1019", "Paper1020", "Paper1021", "Paper1022", "Paper1023", "Paper1024", "Paper1025", "Paper1026", "Paper1027", "Paper1028", "Paper1029", "Paper1030", "Paper1031", "Paper1032", "Paper1033", "Paper1034", "Paper1035", "Paper1036", "Paper1037", "Paper1038", "Paper1039", "Paper1040", "Paper1041", "Paper1042", "Paper1043", "Paper1044", "Paper1045", "Paper1046", "Paper1047", "Paper1048", "Paper1049", "Paper1050", "Paper1051", "Paper1052", "Paper1053", "Paper1054", "Paper1055", "Paper1056", "Paper1057", "Paper1058", "Paper1059", "Paper1060", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "")

TandF <- c("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "Paper641", "", "", "", "", "", "Paper647", "Paper648", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "Paper676", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "Paper700", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "Paper1061", "Paper1062", "Paper1063", "Paper1064", "Paper1065", "Paper1066", "Paper1067", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "")

dat <- data.frame(IEEE,SpringerNature,TandF)

fit <- euler(dat)
plot(fit)
```

When I execute the code, the following error message is thrown for IEEE:

> Error: unexpected string constant in: ", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",
> "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",
> "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",
> "", "", "", "", "", "", ""
> """

This error message is **not** thrown for SpringerNature and TandF, although I created them the same way as I did with IEEE by coding beforehand.

I also tried to at least execute the code without the troublesome IEEE, i.e. I adjusted

```
dat <- data.frame(IEEE,SpringerNature,TandF)
```

to

```
dat <- data.frame(SpringerNature,TandF)
```

but then when the program gets to the line `fit <- euler(dat)` R crashes.

Does anyone have an idea:

1. how to fix the data assignment?
2. why the program crashes? Are there too many values and too many euler sets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the crashing-problem by formulating the intersections like this (numbers are examplary):

```
library(eulerr)

fit <- euler(c(
"IEEE" = 30,
"SpringerNature" = 50,
"TandF" = 87,
"IEEE&SpringerNature" = 7,
"SpringerNature&TandF" = 9,
"IEEE&SpringerNature&TandF" = 1))

plot(fit)
```